# Hql error with-clause in LEFT JOIN

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, hibernate, hql

after several days of research I still have not found the solution.

I have this HQL request that throw a querySyntaxException :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements [SELECT patDataset.patient.sId , patData ,proDataset.professional.sId, proData  FROM com.inovelan.cloud.persistence.server.entities.DataSet patDataset INNER JOIN patDataset.patient patient with patient. sId in (:patientSidList) LEFT JOIN patient.patientProfessionals ppRole with ppRole.id.roleCodingOidcodesystem= :codeSystem AND ppRole.id.roleCodingCode=:codingCode  LEFT JOIN ppRole.professional proRole  LEFT JOIN proRole.dataSet proDataset with proDataset.archive =:archive  LEFT JOIN proDataset.dataProfessionals proData with proData.itemDefinition.id.id in (:proItemDefs)  INNER JOIN patDataset.dataSetDefinition patDatasetDef with patDatasetDef.id.id in(:patDatasetDefIdList) INNER JOIN patDataset.dataPatients patData  LEFT JOIN patDataset.dataPatients data_patient_PAT_SEXE with ( data_patient_PAT_SEXE.itemDefinition.id.id=:data_patient_PAT_SEXE AND patDataset.dataSetDefinition.id.id ='DIRECTORY_PATIENT')  LEFT JOIN patDataset.dataPatients data_patient_PAT_NOM_NAISSANCE with ( data_patient_PAT_NOM_NAISSANCE.itemDefinition.id.id=:data_patient_PAT_NOM_NAISSANCE AND patDataset.dataSetDefinition.id.id ='DIRECTORY_PATIENT')  LEFT JOIN patDataset.dataPatients data_patient_PAT_PRENOM with ( data_patient_PAT_PRENOM.itemDefinition.id.id=:data_patient_PAT_PRENOM AND patDataset.dataSetDefinition.id.id ='DIRECTORY_PATIENT')  WHERE patDataset.archive=:archive  AND patient.active=:patientState  AND ( patDatasetDef.id.id =:dataset_def_pat_DIRECTORY_PATIENT AND patData.itemDefinition.id.id in (:itemdef_list_pat_DIRECTORY_PATIENT)  ) AND patDataset.date = (SELECT MAX(patDataset2.date) FROM com.inovelan.cloud.persistence.server.entities.DataSet patDataset2 WHERE patDataset2.dataSetDefinition.id.id = patDataset.dataSetDefinition.id.id AND patDataset2.patient.sId =  patDataset.patient.sId) ORDER BY (CASE WHEN data_patient_PAT_SEXE.stringValue IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), data_patient_PAT_SEXE.stringValue ASC,(CASE WHEN data_patient_PAT_NOM_NAISSANCE.stringValue IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), data_patient_PAT_NOM_NAISSANCE.stringValue ASC,(CASE WHEN data_patient_PAT_PRENOM.stringValue IS NULL then 1 ELSE 0 END), data_patient_PAT_PRENOM.stringValue ASC]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:91)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:109)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:158)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:93)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:167)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:301)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:236)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1836)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:342)
```

I extracted the request to make it more understandable and the reason of this "left join" is to sort metadata (it's not always add to request) :

```
SELECT patDataset.patient.sId,
   patData
FROM DataSet patDataset
INNER JOIN patDataset.patient patient
INNER JOIN patDataset.dataSetDefinition patDatasetDef WITH patDatasetDef.id.id IN(:patDatasetDefIdList)
LEFT JOIN patDataset.dataPatients data_patient_PAT_SEXE WITH (data_patient_PAT_SEXE.itemDefinition.id.id='SEXE'
                                                          AND patDatasetDef.id.id ='DIRECTORY_PATIENT')
WHERE patDataset.archive=:archive
AND patient.active=:patientState
ORDER BY (CASE
          WHEN data_patient_PAT_SEXE.stringValue IS NULL THEN 1
          ELSE 0
      END), data_patient_PAT_SEXE.stringValue ASC
```

I already tried in SQL and what I want to do works perfectly

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dataPatient datapatien1 ON dataset.sId=datapatien1.dataSetSid
AND (datapatien1.itemDefinitionId ='SEXE')
AND datasetdef.id ='DIRECTORY_PATIENT'
```

I've heard about this issue in hibernate https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7321
but i work with hibernate 5.2, it should be ok

I've already checked the similar question, but no one has the same case

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

HQL generates this error because of "patDatasetDef.id.id" statement. It gets problem in parsing this statement.

Instead You have to use join operation on joined object like below :
**select mother, offspr, mate.name
from DomesticCat as mother
    inner join mother.mate as mate
    left outer join mother.kittens as offspr**

Use Reference :
[For reference use this link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)